# Element is not displayed until click on button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write my first script using Selenium WebDriver 3.0.2.
I would like to automate adding to a library a book from PACKT pub.
[PACKT Pub Free Learning](https://www.packtpub.com/packt/offers/free-learning)

In first step I'm clicking on button login to show fields to input login and password.
In second step I'm trying to find input field, but my code raise exception "ElementNotVisibleException".

How should I proceed with this problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Ie(r"C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe")
browser.get('https://www.packtpub.com/packt/offers/free-learning')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('login-popup').click()
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
elem.send_keys('selenium')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 `input` fields with same `id` attribute. You can check it with

```
print(len(browser.find_elements_by_id('email')))
```

The first is hidden, so you need to handle second one:

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_id('email')[1]
elem.send_keys('selenium')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!